# Как с помощью Microsoft Bot Framework сделать кнопки в несколько рядов?

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot, bot-framework

Нужно создать несколько рядов `keyboard` кнопок с разным их количеством в ряду для Telegram.
Как сделать один ряд понятно, но не пойму как сделать из этого несколько рядов с контролируемым количеством кнопок в ряду.

```
    msg.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
{
    Actions = new List<CardAction>()
    {
        new CardAction(){ Title = "Пользователь", Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value="Пользователь" },
        new CardAction(){ Title = "Сервера", Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value="Сервера" },
        new CardAction(){ Title = "Сеть", Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value="Сеть" },
        new CardAction(){ Title = "Консультант", Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value="Консультант" }
    }
};
```

Comment: клавиатуры в телеграм - это массивы массивов, может в этом проблема? код бы показали или что там есть

Comment: @Anatol
`msg.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
            {
                Actions = new List<CardAction>()
                {
                    new CardAction(){ Title = "Пользователь", Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value="Пользователь" },
                    new CardAction(){ Title = "Сервера", Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value="Сервера" },
                    new CardAction(){ Title = "Сеть", Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value="Сеть" },
                    new CardAction(){ Title = "Консультант", Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value="Консультант" }
                }
            }; `

Comment: Код в вопрос добавьте, нечитабельно же

Comment: @Anatol добавил

Comment: что делает этот код?

Comment: это обычные кнопки или инлайн?

Comment: @Anatol обычные